# MAX IF the prior cell equals TRUE in EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel

EDITED TO INCLUDE EXAMPLE:
How do I display MAX number from a row only IF the prior cell equals to TRUE?[image]

I want to display the latest date from an attended event. But only if the person has attended the event.

As you can see, John's last event date attended should be 2/13/2019 but the formula I have now only gets the greatest day not taking into account if the person attended the event or not. Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1510515/edit) to include sample data and expected result? as it is, all we can say is "Embed the `MAXIFS` statement in an `IF`"

Comment: I have updated the question to add the example. I'm still having a hard time with this one!

Answer (score 2):

If you have MAXIFS:

```
=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,TRUE)
```

If not then you can do AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,$B$1:$B100/($A$1:$A$100),1)
```

or this array formula:

```
=MAX(IF($A$1:$A$100,$B$1:$B100))
```

This last one requires the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

The last two are array type formula and as such the referenced ranges should be limited to the data sets.

Answer (score 1):

short-answer is to do matrix math!

Basically, we can take the columns and multiply them together, then find the "MAX".  "True" has the value of 1, where as "False" has a value of 0. Assuming your "true/false" column is "A", and your value column is "B", you'll want something like:

```
=MAX(($A:$A)*($B:$B))
```

**IMPORTANT**

In order to do the matrix math... Excel requires you to press <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> for matrix math.  Simply typing the formula and pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> will not work.

[image]

There is one gotchya with this method... this will have issues with negative numbers... as false columns will evaluate to 0... and therefore, the max will be 0.

Comment: But if you do: `=MAX(IF(A:A,B:B))` it does not matter.

Comment: Good point.  Why not submit an answer? :)

Comment: Working on it, now